# How to have a category not show up in query post with page panigation?

Tags: categories, query-posts, exclude

Basically I have this loop that shows all post. Inside of it I want to exclude post's from categories including shirts and hoodies, also the gallery category. Here is what I have so far.

the code works without the 'cat=-gallery". But with it, it does not show any post's at all.

```
<?php
$limit = 5;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts( 'cat=-gallery&showposts=' . $limit . '&paged=' . $paged );
$wp_query->is_category = true; $wp_query->is_home = false;
?>

 <-----my blog stuff---->

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php next_posts_link('Older Entries »', 0); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using cat in the query you need to specify the category id not name. Try this.

```
<?php
$gallery = get_cat_id('gallery');
$shirts = get_cat_id('shirts');
$hoodies = get_cat_id('hoodies');
$excluded_cats = '-'.$gallery.',-'.$shirts.',-'.$hoodies;
$limit = 5;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts( 'cat='.$excluded_cats.'&showposts=' . $limit . '&paged=' . $paged );
?>
```

Comment: ugh. Ive been waiting for you. Thank you. Im new to wp. I was trying to find the id value but figured it would use the name as well. But this worked. Again, thank you!